# Number sequence 6

Tags: number-sequence

Fill in the correct number in this sequence:

$16,32,40,88,92,172,?$

The options are: $178$,$176$,$174\frac{2}{3}$,$177$, and $175\frac{1}{3}$

At first, I thought the pattern was $2x+8$ but that does not work out.

Source: a publicly available practice test in a book.

Answer (score 2):

> Take the differences $A(n+1) - A(n)$. This gives the following sequence:
>  $16, 8, 48, 4, 80$
>  We can note that:
>  $16/2 = 8, 8*6 = 48, 48/12 = 4, 4*20 = 80$, i.e.
>  $a(n)/2 = a(n+1), a(n+1)*6 = a(n+2), a(n+2)/12 = a(n+3), a(n+3)*20 = a(n+4)$
>  So we get alternating division and multiplication using a 3rd sequence:
>  $2, 6, 12, 20$ which looks like this [oeis sequence](https://oeis.org/A002378). ($0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30$).
>  So the next number is 30. Now going in reverse order we have:
>  $a(n+4)/30 = a(n+5)$, or $80/30 = a(n+5)$. So in the original sequence the next number will be:
>  $172 + 80/30 = 172 + 8/3 = 174\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> Count the holes in the decimal digits
>  16 -> 1
>  32 -> 0
>  40 -> 2
>  88 -> 4
>  92 -> 1
>  172 -> 0
>
>  1, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, X
>  X=2 (by simple repetition)
>
>  So, ? has 2 holes. The only option that fits the bill is 178.

...

> If a 4 has zero holes, then we have 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, X and then 176 would be the only option instead.